# phpbrew php7 throws gnutls_handshake() failed: Illegal parameter

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssl, phpbrew

I've compiled php7.1.30 on ubuntu 14.04 successfully.
When I test that peace of code

```php
/ Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://buy.itunes.apple.com',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'item1' => 'value',
        'item2' => 'value2'
    ]
]);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources

if (!$resp) {
    echo('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
   echo "\n";
}
curl_close($curl);
```

I got error `Error: "gnutls_handshake() failed: Illegal parameter" - Code: 35`

The verbose output is that:

```
 Rebuilt URL to: https://buy.itunes.apple.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 17.173.66.180...
* Connected to buy.itunes.apple.com (17.173.66.180) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Illegal parameter
* Closing connection 0
```

From time to time this works successfully it seems that apple TLS support is not consistent.

However if I build the same code on Ubuntu 18.04 it works 100% and if I run the same code with php 5.5.9 (dist version) again 100% working.

So far I plan to upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 in order to get the working because I fail to overcome above issue. I've tried different /etc/ssl/cert ca files but unsuccessfully.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to get that working in the change openssl-dev lib on ubuntu with the newer one and recompile again.

However I decide to get rid of ubuntu 14.04 in your infrastructure - speed the planned discount of Ubuntu 14 and replace with amazon linux 2.